# Getting individual values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

PHP :

```
<?php 
print_r($details);
?>
```

Hi friends i'm printing the value of $details in php code and the out put i got in browser is as follows.

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => 
        Array ( [item_id] => 8 [row] => [merchant_id] => 1 [discount] => [currentController] => store [price] => 60|Large [qty] => 1 [notes] => [cooking_ref] => Cooking reference 1 

            [ingredients] => Array ( [0] => Ingredients 1 ) [require_addon_5] => 2 
            [sub_item] => Array (
                [5] => Array ( [0] => 2|10|Addon Item 1|right [1] => 3|20|Addon Item 2|right ) 
                [6] => Array ( [0] => 2|10|Addon Item 1|right [1] => 3|20|Addon Item 2|right ) 
                [7] => Array ( [0] => 2|10|Addon Item 1|right [1] => 3|20|Addon Item 2|right ) 
                                ) 
            [addon_qty] => Array (
             [5] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
             [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
             [7] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) 
                                ) 
            [require_addon_6] => 2 
            [require_addon_7] => 2 
            [two_flavors] =>
            [non_taxable] => 2 
            [addon_ids] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 2 [5] => 3 ) 
            ) 
        )
```

Now I've to get the values of 'item_id' , 'cooking_ref' , sub_item and addon_qty as an individual array . Now I would like to know how can we access these values . I have tried something like

```
<?php
 print_r($details);
 echo "item_id : ".$details[0]['item_id']" <br />"
 echo "price : ".$details[0]['price']" <br />"
 echo "cooking_ref : ".$details[0]['cooking_ref']" <br />"
 echo "cooking_ref : ".$details[0]['cooking_ref']" <br />"
 echo "ingredients : "" <br />";

foreach($details['sub_item'] as $sub_item)
{
    print_r($sub_item);
    echo "<br /><br />";
    $sub_item_array_val +=1;
}
?>
```

But didnt workedout for me could any one please suggest me how to acces these values from the above array , thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing `$details['sub_item']` with `$details[0]['sub_item']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible approach-

```
foreach($details as $detail)
{
  echo "item_id: ".$detail['item_id']."<br/>";
  echo "price: ".$detail['price']."<br/>";
  echo "cooking_ref: ".$detail['cooking_ref']."<br/>";

  foreach($detail[$sub_item] as $sub_item)
  {
    echo "ingredients:  <br/>";
    print_r($sub_item);
    echo "<br/><br/>";
  }

  foreach($detail[$addon_qty] as $addon_qty)
  {
    echo "ingredients: <br/>";
    print_r($addon_qty);
    echo "<br/><br/>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$details = // your array;

foreach($details as $detail)
{
   echo $detail['item_id'];   // will return 8
   echo $detail['cooking_ref'];   // will return Cooking reference 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach should be

```
foreach($details[0]['sub_item'] as $sub_item)
    {
        print_r($sub_item);
        echo "<br /><br />";

    }
```